# Recyclerview inside fragment inside viewpager notifydatasetchanged not working

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, notifydatasetchanged

I have a recyclerview inside a fragment and that fragment is inside a view pager.

notifydatasetchanged() is not working even though the same code works in other projects of mine. The only difference I can see is that it is inside a view pager now?.

This is how notify the change:

```
public void updateRecyler(){

    // Clear the current array
    alarmsFromSP.clear();
    // Update the array (This is working the array size is changing)
    alarmsFromSP.addAll(AlarmCollection.getAlarms(getActivity()));
    // Notify the change
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

I create the recylerview in oncreate like this:

```
public class FragmentAllAlarms extends Fragment  {

    // Arraylist of the alarm data from the strings
    ArrayList<Alarm> alarmsFromSP;
    tabRefreshReceiver r;
    RecyclerView rv;
    AlarmsAdapter adapter;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_all_alarms, container, false);

        // Recycler
        rv = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.mainAlarmRecyclerView);
        rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

        // Get saved data for alarms from the shared preferences string
        alarmsFromSP = AlarmCollection.getAlarms(getActivity());
        System.out.println("StringIs"+alarmsFromSP.size());

        // Adapter
        adapter = new AlarmsAdapter(getActivity(), alarmsFromSP);
        rv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Is it possible I am losing reference to the array or is it somthing to do with the viewpager?

I have been stuck with this for two days now any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

make sure that `updateRecyler()` is called,
and try to change `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` to `rv.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();`

this worked for me once.

Answer (score -1):

I have faced the same problem, then I found a temporary solution, instead of using `notifyDataSetChanged()` use

```
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
recyclerView.scrollToPosition(postion);
```